# Elm Function argument Type Mismatch

Tags: function, elm

I have a function with this signature in elm:

```
updateThing : ThingMsg -> Model -> Model
updateThing dmsg model =
    case dmsg of
        Name name->
            let ...
```

And try to call it as this:

```
updateThing( Name "Test", model )
```

But get the argument mismatch compile error:

```
   The argument to function `updateThing` is causing a mismatch.

   24| updateThing( Name "Test", model )
                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Function `updateThing` is expecting the argument to be:

       ThingMsg

   But it is:

       ( ThingMsg, Model )
```

I sure am expecting it to be ( ThingMsg, Model ) what did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to call function `f` with arguments `a` and `b` you need the following code in `Elm`:

```
f a b
```

The following syntax:

```
f(a, b)
```

will call the `f` with an argument `(a, b)`.

`(a, b)` means a tuple in `Elm`, it's a data structure of a fixed length.

It's probably not convenient, if you came from some other language, which has the second syntax for a function call. That's why you have the type mismatch. The compiler expects to receive `ThingMsg` as a first argument, but you're providing a tuple `( Name "Test", model )`, which is of type `( ThingMsg, Model )`

To fix the error, just correct your calling code to:

```
updateThing (Name "Test") model
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but apparently I just did updateThing( (Name "Test"), model )